# Comparison of two states in corda

Tags: kotlin, corda

I have created two states in corda. Now I want to compare the fields of these two states and create a third state based on the comparison. Is it possible? If possible how to do it? Is there any ideal programming solution other than comparing each field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Kotlin, you can use data classes: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html For example, the following will return `true`:

```
data class Person(val name: String)
val person1 = Person("John")
val person2 = Person("John")
person1 == person2
```

Because equality is determined solely based on the fields in the primary constructor. Alternatively, you can override the `equals` method of your class.

If you are only trying to compare some of the fields, you can compare them directly in a large `if` statement. But if you are using a `data` class, you can also compare them by creating a copy where the fields you **don't** want to compare have been set to be equal in both instances. For example, the following will return `true`:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val address: String)
val person1 = Person("John", 24, "London")
val person2 = Person("John", 25, "London")
person1 == person2.copy(age = person1.age)
```

Comment: val loadingState = LoadingState("T1", "NET", 100, ourIdentity, "Initiated")
            val loadingState2 = LoadingState( "T2","NET", 100, ourIdentity, "Initiated")
            if (loadingState === loadingState2 ){
                loadingState.updateStatus("Cleared")
            }else{
                loadingState.updateStatus("Not cleared")
            }

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yep, as long as they're `data` classes :)

Comment: Thank you. But what if I have a requirement that I want to compare only 3 fields out of the 5 fields from both the states? How do I filter it then?